# unable to start an android app logact showing null pointer and classcast exception, the java file and xml file is as shown below

Tags: android

this is the code used in tha java class.it doesnt show any errors in eclipse.the logcat shows null pointer exception and class caste exception

```
package com.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;


public class MyfirstappActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

int count ;
Button add,sub;
TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    count = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_one);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub_one);
    txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count = count + 1;
            txt.setText("Your total is " + count);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count = count - 1;
            txt.setText("Your total is " + count);
        }
    }); 

}
```

this is the main.xml layout file created. i tried cleaning the project meanwhile.tried using the try catch mechanism.the app s running fine when i commented the button referncing part of the above code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="60dp" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

   <Button
       android:text="@string/add1"
       android:layout_gravity="center" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:id="@+id/add_one"
       android:textSize="40dp"
       android:gravity="center">
   </Button>

   <Button
       android:text="@string/sub1"
       android:layout_gravity="center" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:id="@+id/sub_one"
       android:textSize="40dp"
       android:gravity="center">
   </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: setContentView should be called before findViewById..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txt` is `TextView`, you are Casting it to button. Use

```
txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

Also you need set the Layout resource for this. So use,

```
super.onCreate();
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**Edit-** You code should be something like,

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
count = 0;
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_one);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub_one);
txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

Comment: oh..i am sorry,,. i asked it.. i kept checking a lot... thats why posted at the end..

Comment: @RoyceRaju  You have to use **setContentView(R.layout.main)** before initialing objects.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

to

```
 txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

because you are trying to cast TextView to Button and assigning it to TextView instance . also move  `setContentView(R.layout.main);` before initializing UI elements  as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   //<<< set layout for Activity here
    // access UI elements here
```

Answer (score 0):

please write this way...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   count = 0;
   add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_one);
   sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub_one);
   txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
}
```

and change the

```
txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

to

```
txt = (Textview) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

Answer (score 0):

setcontentview needs to be written after super.oncreate like :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You set layout after init the view object it that's why getting null pointer change to this

```
super.onCreate();
setContentView(R.layout.main);
// then init the object, Here need to set layout first then find view by id
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_one); 
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub_one);
txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display); // here you cast to button change to TextView
```

Answer (score 0):

because you cast textview to button and you also calling ID of buttons and text view before setcontentview so that's why you got error.
try this :-

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
count = 0;
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_one);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub_one);
txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        count = count + 1;
        txt.setText("Your total is " + count);
    }
    });

sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        count = count - 1;
        txt.setText("Your total is " + count);
    }
}); 

}
}
```